# Sugar ORM querying multiple columns

Tags: android, orm, sugarorm

this my model class for sugar orm project how should i query and get all "num" values in a list like i am able to do for "title" using query
   => List<> all = Attend.listAll(Attend.class);

```
public class Attend extends SugarRecord{
String title;
int num;

public Attend() {
}
public Attend(String title, int num) {
    this.title = title;

    this.num = num;


}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getNum() {
    return num;
}


public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return   title  ;
}}
```

Comment: So you wan't to query all num values to list<Integer> ?

Comment: yup.. Suleiman19 just gave me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
List<Attend> attends = Attend.listAll(Attend.class);

List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();

for (Attend attend : attends)
   nums.add(attend.getNum());
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't retrieve a single column from sugarorm to list, Sugar ORM github issues page says that , it will be added to 1.6.0 version, the current sugar ORM version was 1.4.0.
 [Source](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/270)